Box constraints for Karush-Kuhn-Tucker
Let $f(x) = ax+b$. I want to apply the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) algorithm, with the box contraints on $x$, $-c\leq x \leq c$.
I am following this tutorial. I formulated my problem as:
$$\qquad \qquad\min_{x} f(x) $$
$$\qquad \qquad s.t. g_1(x) = x \geq -c $$
$$ \qquad \qquad g_2(x) = -x \geq -c$$
I have split the condition into two conditions and multiplied one of them by $-1
$, so that the condition will conform with what I understand is the canonical form: $g_i(x) -b_i \geq 0$ (is this correct?).
Now, I tried setting this all in a matrix and find the inverse:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \lambda_1(\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}) - \lambda_2(\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x}) = 0 \Rightarrow a - \lambda_1(1) - \lambda_2(-1) = 0$$
$$g_1(x) = x = -c$$
$$g_2(x) = -x = -c$$
The last two lines are only true if $x = 0$. So, did I make a wrong turn here, or is this method simply not suited for box constraints?

You made a wrong turn with the last two (complementary) constraints, which should include $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively.

I am confused. I don't understand what you mean by this answer. The condition is $\lambda_i(g_i(x^) - b_i) = 0$. This means that either $\lambda_i = 0$ or $g_i(x^) - b_i = 0$. We solve for $g_i(x^*) - b_i = 0$ assuming $\lambda_i > 0$, and if we find that the solution gives us $\lambda_i \leq 0$, we set $\lambda_i = 0$ and resolve. What am I missing here?

Your comment contains the correct complementary constraints, which differ from what you wrote in your question. In your question, you consider only one of four cases for the two disjunctions. Unless $c=0$, that case cannot occur.

Doesn't it come down to the same thing? Solving $g_i(x^) - b_i  = 0$ or $g_i(x^) = b_i$? I'm still not getting it.

I think it will become clearer if you explicitly write down the four cases and consider them one at a time. The three you haven’t considered will lead to $x$ being at one of the two endpoints or (when $a=0$) $x$ being anywhere in the interval.
